# Apply click event only to the targeted class jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

This question might be asked earlier, but I was not able to grasp the answers since there were a lot bunch of codes in every questions. I don't know how to put it in words. I think you guys will understand the situation once you see the code.

**HTML**

```
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="large-9 columns">
                                    <h3>By Christian Christiansen</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-3 columns">
                                    <p class="raty"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-11 large-offset-1 columns">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, quasi nisi optio, earum facilis perspiciatis temporibus nobis nam velit incidunt. Recusandae accusamus pariatur, explicabo iure ea ex perspiciatis perferendis quam!</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-8 columns">
                                    <img src="images/comments.png" alt="">
                                    <p class="inline_cmt">Comments (3)</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-2 columns">
                                    <img src="images/reply.png" alt="">
                                    <p class="inline_rply">Reply</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-2 columns">
                                    <img src="images/report.png" alt="">
                                    <p class="inline_rep">Report</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-12 columns reply_box">
                                    <label>
                                        <textarea placeholder="submit your reply here.."></textarea>
                                    </label>
                                    <a href="#" class="button right">Submit</a>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="large-9 columns">
                                    <h3>By Christian Christiansen</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-3 columns">
                                    <p class="raty"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-11 large-offset-1 columns">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, quasi nisi optio, earum facilis perspiciatis temporibus nobis nam velit incidunt. Recusandae accusamus pariatur, explicabo iure ea ex perspiciatis perferendis quam!</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-8 columns">
                                    <img src="images/comments.png" alt="">
                                    <p class="inline_cmt">Comments (3)</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-2 columns">
                                    <img src="images/reply.png" alt="">
                                    <p class="inline_rply">Reply</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-2 columns">
                                    <img src="images/report.png" alt="">
                                    <p class="inline_rep">Report</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-12 columns reply_box">
                                    <label>
                                        <textarea class="custom_textarea" placeholder="submit your reply here.."></textarea>
                                    </label>
                                    <a href="#" class="button right">Submit</a>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                            </div>


<div class="large-12 columns reply_box">
     <label>
       <textarea placeholder="submit your reply here.."></textarea>
     </label>
     <a href="#" class="button right">Submit</a>
</div>
```

I have the same html multiple times in my code, What I want to achieve is, I want the `div` with classname `reply_box` to appear whenever I click the element with classname `inline_reply`. I have used jQuery toggle method to achieve this and the code is,

**jQuery**

```
    $(".inline_rply").click(function() {
        $(".reply_box").toggle();
    });
```

*My Problem:* Whenever I click the reply button, all the elements having the classname `reply_box` are toggled whereas **I just want to toggle only the one that I have clicked**. I don't want to add different classnames to all `div's` since there will be numerous posts. Is there an easy way to do it? I heard that this can be done using `this`. But I donno how. Anyone with a simple example will be much appreciated. I think I have not confused you guys.

Comment: what is the correlation between the divs with classnames `large-2` and `large-12` is that a typo ??

Comment: they are not related. I know that is confusing. I have just randomly picked the `div's` just to show where my class exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as i think you have to use the **next** keyword as the following

```
$(".inline_rply").click(function() {
        $(this).closest('div').next('.reply_box').toggle();
    });
```

** updation as per your html **

There is an another div having text **Report**, so for this you can use **next** again as following

```
$(".inline_rply").click(function() {
        $(this).closest('div').next().next('.reply_box').toggle();
    });
```

**next()** traverse the node one by one as per the selector.

Hope it helps...

Comment: This works too. Now I am confused which one to use LOL. Which has more possibilities?

Comment: **.closest()** api traverse up and find the first and stop traversing, but **.parent()** traverse each parent till the end of the document. i want to say **.closest()** is faster than the **.parent()**.

Comment: **.closest()** api works for me now. So I think I should use that given that I have a speed advantage.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just apply this and check may be solve your problem .

```
$(".inline_rply").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().next(".reply_box").toggle();
    });
```

**Updated Answer**

```
$(".inline_rply").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().next().next(".reply_box").toggle();
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jx2a7uuv/)**

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jx2a7uuv/1/)**

Comment: Doesn't work. But not your mistake I guess. I have updated the `html` part of my question with two occurences of same code for which I want to apply click.

Answer (score 1):

use `this` to target current element

```
$(".inline_rply").click(function() {
      $(this).closest('div.large-2').next(".reply_box").toggle(); // this will be the clicked 
});
```

`.closest()` will get the nearest parent element specified with class name and with `next()` you can target the next `.reply_box` class containing element.

Comment: Thank you `closest` or `parent` ? which one should I use? Both are working now.

Comment: @ThomasSebastian You should use `.closest().